# "Server block is not well formed" in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This is a duplicate of an unanswered question.  In VS2013, I have an .aspx page that when I try to open it, it suddenly shows a messagebox with "Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file... with Unicode encoding. Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents".  When I open it with notepad, it consists of non-English characters.  I have no clue where to start looking for the problem.  The web site builds with no errors.  Anyone have any ideas where I can start troubleshooting?  I have made no other recent changes to my local IIS or anything else on my laptop.

Comment: So perhaps including the erroneous file!! Sounds like it's been corrupted in some way. Is it just the one file. If it's just the one file then fix it manually in notepad and move on!

Comment: I agree, it's been corrupted.  But how?  That's my question. This is the second time this has happened, and it has only ever happened with VS2013.  Yes, it's just one file.  But fix it in notepad?  How, when all my finely-crafted, hand-tuned ASP.NET HTML has been translated to non-English characters?  Are you offering to translate it back?  Yeah, that would be... Great.

Comment: Lol, oh, I see! Basic question, have you run any disk scans to see if its the disk that's corrupt. Maybe deleting that one file completely and downloading again from source control (...assuming you have it) will sort it, if it's just that one file. Or... https://translate.google.com ;-)

Comment: It sounds like it might be an encoding mismatch. Could your source control system be converting files away from UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

For what it matters now, for this problem on my machine, I found I was using a reference to a namespace in the partial view that was being called but it was not being used. I removed the namespace @Import and the error went away.